# Why I use the waitpid in parent process, but the child process is still running after the parent process?

Tags: c, linux

The program is below

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<unistd.h>
#include<sys/wait.h>
#include<sys/types.h>

int main(int argc,char **argv)
{
    int fds[2];
    int error=pipe(fds);
    if(error==-1)
    {
        perror("pipe");
        return 1;
    }
    int ret=fork();
    if(ret<0)
    {perror("fork failed");
        return 1;
    }
    else if(ret==0)
    {
        close(fds[0]);
        close(1);
        dup(fds[1]); char *argv[3];
        argv[0]="ls";
        argv[1]="-l";
        argv[2]=NULL;
        execvp(argv[0],argv);
    }
    else
    {   
        int rett=fork();
        if(rett<0)
        {
            perror("fork failed");
            return 1;
        }
        else if(rett==0)
        {
            close(fds[1]);///
            close(0);
            dup(fds[0]);                

            char *argv[2];
            argv[0]="wc";
            argv[1]=NULL;
            execvp(argv[0],argv);       
        }
        else
        {
            waitpid(ret,NULL,7);     /// wait for child process
            waitpid(rett,NULL,7);    //// wait for another child process
            printf("Process %d finished\n",ret);
            printf("Process %d finished\n",rett);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

There is the outcome below; why is `printf` is executing before the "wc"?

```
Process 7189 finished
Process 7190 finished
zyy@ubuntu:~$      24     209    1125
```

Answer (score 1):

Check your return values functions that can return errors. And don't use magic numbers instead of correct flags.

Your `waitpid` calls don't actually wait for any process to finish and just return errors. What does your magic number "7" mean? That's not what the documentation tells you to do. One of the bits in the number 7 is WNOHANG, which tells `waitpid` to not actually wait for the children to finish. Another bit in those flags is valid, but quite useless since you're not doing any `ptrace` on your processes. The third bit is invalid and will make `waitpid` error our immediately. I'm not going to tell you which is which because you're not supposed to do it this way at all. Read the manual page.

Another problem that you have is that you need to close the pipe in the parent process as well. `wc` will try to read data from the pipe (on its stdin) until the pipe is closed and it still remains open in the parent. The reason `wc` always prints after the parent has exited is that it's the parent exit that closes the pipe and that makes wc finish reading.